# Run Unit Tests on Coded UI and Selenium infrastructures together

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, coded-ui-tests

Can i run unit tests on Coded ui and selenium infrastructures together ? 
For example: 
Call methods from selenium infra and coded ui methods to the same test i am building in unit tests layer?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: because the application that i am running on contains both silverlight and angular js Development on the same web app.

Comment: Selenium has a silverlight extension